# Mapping sftp/scp as a drive letter without user logins

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, ssh, scp, netbios

I'm trying to find a software which could map sftp/scp services to a windows drive letter. I know there are quite a bunch of those available, but i haven't found a single one which could run with SYSTEM or Netservice privileges or have decent command line options so i could elevate the program myself. The mapped drive should be available for other services running on the same server.

Most of the programs (sftp netdrive, expandrive, etc) have only option to start automatically only when someone logs in. Because of that they are useless to me.
Their inability to handle non-interactive starts is a bummer too.

FTP->SFTP wrappers don't count as solution despite of integrated windows support for ftp drives. The way they are handled in windows makes ftp mapping unusable without some external ftp drive mapper software. That just adds unnecessary complexity to the solution.

No SMB either (long story / netbios bug).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't find what you are looking for is because it's not practical in Windows.

A drive is mapped only within an active session.  If you had a tool which ran as a service, it would map the drives OK, but the mappings would only be usable by the service.  The mappings would not propagate to your interactive session when you logged on, nor would they be available to other services running on the machine.

This is why all of the tools you have located already only create their mappings when the user logs on to the workstation - because it really is the only practical way to create drive mappings for interactive sessions on Windows.

Comment: The mapping needs to be usable only by other services or SYSTEM, not the other users. This server rarely even sees any logins. I do need a way to make that drive usable to other services.

Comment: For a clarification, i need a way to mount a drive from a solaris cluster which runs only ssh and samba. SMB is out of the question because of a severe netbios bug in windows 2008 concerning bonded NICs. This bug was identified by MS a while back. No fix.

Comment: And i can circumvent the drive available for services with a helper service (wrap 2 or more services in one). But i still need a sftp / scp drive mapper which can operate from command line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service

Comment: @Temotodochi: If you cannot use SMB, there's always NFS.

Answer (score 0):

I use [win-sshfs](https://www.ohloh.net/p/win-sshfs/), a SSH(SFTP) filesystem made using Dokan and SSH.NET library.

It has only `cmd` access. I'm not sure, but you could try run iy as a service.